# "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." When Using Drive API to host videos

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm getting an error using Google's Drive API. Since the videos I want to host on my website are larger than 200 MB, I've been using the Drive API to create a direct download link to use as my video source. I was able to do this by using the ID of the video and an API key from my Google Dev Console and creating a link that looks like this:
`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/videoID?alt=media&key=APIkey`

However, as of late, I've been receiving this error when the video link is clicked:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Is there a way to increase the limit of unauthenticated use without needing to have the user sign up?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of how you call the API? Without sensitive data in it.

Comment: @JoseVasquez I didn't use much code at all when calling the API, I simply used the `video` tag in HTML and used the link format `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<videoID>?alt=media&key=<APIkey>`, where I replace `videoID` with the actual ID of the video and `APIkey` with the API key I generated using the Drive API. That way, the video can be used as a source that can be streamed on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use embedded item instead

As mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/1950766/how-do-i-embed-videos-from-my-google-drive-google-photos-into-a-blogger-post-embed-is-no-more?hl=en&msgid=1996729), you can embed your videos into your web page rather than get the file through the Google Drive API.

Bear in mind:

- Google Drive API is intended to develop applications that integrate with Google Drive.
- Google Drive API has a [usage limit](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits) for billing and non-billing accounts.

Having that said I strongly recommend you to use `<iframe>`, since you are using this file in a `<video>` tag.